# How to use Vaccum full in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to test for vaccum in Postgres.

Created a table:

```
create table test_vc(col integer);
```

Inserted multiple records.

```
INSERT INTO test_vc SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

Checked the size of table:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test_vc'));
```

o/p: 36 MB

Deleted multiple records:

```
DELETE FROM test_vc WHERE col > 50000;
```

Again checked the size of table which is still same, i.e. 36 MB.

Then performed VACCUM ino  order to get the free spaces.

```
VACUUM FULL test_vc;
```

But still the size of table remains same, i.e. 36 MB.

If I try using truncate on this table then size comes back to 0 bytes.

Kindly let me know where Vaccum is not being properly performed.

Please find the vaccum setting:
[image]

Comment: Use "Analyze" also as this will update the statistics for the table too.

Comment: No, analyse is also not making any differnece in this. VACUUM FULL Analyze test_vc; size remains the same

Comment: postgres=# create table test_vc(col integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test_vc select * from generate_series(1,1000000);
INSERT 0 1000000
postgres=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test_vc'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 35 MB
(1 row)

postgres=# delete from test_vc where col >50000;
DELETE 950000
postgres=# vacuum full test_vc;
VACUUM
postgres=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test_vc'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 1776 kB
(1 row)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What your vacuum settings ?

Comment: I tried similar for multiple time but with no success. Vaccum didn't removed any space after deletion. I have atteched screenshot for vaccum setting details. kindly look into it and please guide.